# Jquery contains text and make it blue

Tags: jquery, text, contains

The designer want to make the company name in blue, but the company name is embed in the text without any html element surrounding it.

I want to be able to find a string and set only that string to blue

I've got this code, but it makes the whole text in blue

```
$(function() {
    $('div:contains("The Company Name")').css("color","blue");
});
```

this is sample code

```
<div>The company name is great and makes a lot of happy customers</div>
<div>You can have more info on <a href="link">The company name</a>[...]</div>
```

This the result I want

```
<div><span style="color:blue;">The company name</span> is great and makes a lot of happy customers</div>
<div>You can have more info on <a href="link"><span style="color:blue;">The company name</span></a>[...]</div>
```

Anyone?

Comment: It won't even make the first `div` blue as it is *case sensitive*.

Comment: Why do you want to use jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could do it like this as well, if you wish to create the `span` using jQuery instead of just straight off writing `<span style="color:blue;">etc...`:

```
var s = "The company name";
$('div:contains("'+s+'")').html(function(i,e){
    var p = new RegExp(s,"g");
    return e.replace(p,$('<span />').css('color','blue').text(s).wrap('<div />').parent().html());       
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/Mytzh/

Comment: This is perfect, awesome! I don't understand the magic but it works!

Comment: i'm not sure that wrapping with div is OK, because div by default is display: block, just span will be ok

Comment: It's not putting the `div` anywhere. It is wrapping it in an element (this case `div`, but it could be any element), and getting the **contents** of that element (leaving the `div` out of it). Check the output in the example.

Answer (score 2):

```
    $(function() {
    $('div').each(function() {
   $(this).html($(this).html().toString().replace('The Company Name', '<span style="color: blue">The Company Name</span>'));
    });
    });
```

Comment: Will need to change the case of 'The Company Name' to match the example HTML, but the logic is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jQuery highlight plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) to accomplish your goal.